# Using "or" in expressions in filter, angularJS

Tags: angularjs

From the docs:
Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1".

Is it possible to return an array which containg property name: "M" **OR** phone: 1?

Or do I have to write a custom filter for this?

```
ng-options="m.mc_title for m in mainCategories | filter:{mc_schema:activeSchema.sch_id, all:true}"
```

The above code filters where both properties has to be true (&&). I want it to filter if any of them are true (||).

Comment: Do you have any line of code that illustrates your issue? You're using this predicate in a filter of an ngRepeat?

Comment: You probably will need to write a custom filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that, for that, you should define your own filter that handles 'or' expressions as parameters. Here's an example I did for you:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qwJm2fy6JmdWYG2yR2it?p=preview

```
// Receive a JSON with properties that serve as OR clause.
// For example, this one would give you any object whose NAME is JOHN or whose ID is 123.
$scope.model.filteredData = $filter('orArray')($scope.model.data, {name: 'john', id: '123'});
```

The name of the filter is 'orArray' and receives two things:

- The list of elements you want to filter
- A JSON with the properties you want to filter by, specified by `{filterProperty: filterValue}`

**EDIT**: I added the inline filter to the plnkr

```
<li ng-repeat="element in model.data | orArray:{name: 'john', id: '123'}">
```

Comment: Please use React + Codesandbox